# A phone, tablet, or computer **is/are** used with care nowadays because people do not want to get addicted - is or are?

Tags: verbs, subject-verb-agreement

What form of the verb to use when the subjects are joined by a "or" and they are not mutually exclusive?

**Example 1**

> A phone, tablet, or computer **is/are** used with care nowadays because people do not want to get addicted.

**Example 2**

> A healthy diet or a regular exercise routine **is/are** what you need to lose weight.

**Example 3**

> When "no problem," "no worries," or "thank you" **is/are** used, that means the speaker is expressing their care.

Comment: https://grammar.yourdictionary.com/vs/when-to-use-is-vs-are-in-sentences.html

Comment: (1) I would say 'Phones, tablets and computers' because you later refer to 'people', not an individual owner of a device.